# C compiler error: cdefs.h not found

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, glibc

(There are similar questions answered but none really applies to this)

I have a board with Fedora 20 and armv71 architecture (32-bit). I have installed all the gcc libraries via yum which are required such as `gcc`, `g++`, `cmake`, `glibc`, `glibc-devel` etc. (`glibc-devel` is equivalent of `libc6-dev-i386` in Fedora).

I'm trying to compile a C project, which compiles just fine on MAC OS 64-bit and Ubuntu 64-bit, but gives me the following error on Fedora 20 when I run **`make`**:

```
/usr/include/features.h:364:25: fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory
 #  include <sys/cdefs.h>
```

When I check `/usr/include/sys` folder, it is empty and `cdefs.h` file does not exist anywhere on the system.

The problem seems to be I'm missing a package (possibly?) but cannot figure out which one is missing since I seem to have all installed. Or 32-bit C compiler missing that file for a specific reason? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Running `make`" can effectively do anything. You need to show the compiler invocation command. That's usually hidden in the rule with an `@` symbol in the beginning of the line. Simply remove the `@` to see what's actually going on.

Comment: Check this thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/470796/fatal-error-sys-cdefs-h-no-such-file-or-directory. Basically you just have to install libc6-dev-i386

Comment: I've seen that thread but the equivalent of libc6-dev-i386 in Fedora is glibc-devel, check this thread: http://superuser.com/questions/491504/how-do-i-install-package-libc6-dev-i386-on-fedora 

However, I have glibc and glibc-devel installed in my system (updated the question as well)

Comment: On my Fedora 22 `/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h` is provided by the package `glibc-headers`.

Comment: `glibc-headers` is also installed with this version:  `glibc-headers-2.18-19.fc20.armv7hl`

Comment: Checking the [rpms](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=glibc-headers%28armv7hl%29) `cdefs.h` is included in them.

Answer (score 5):

using this command (or a similar one, depending on your OS)

```
apt-get install libc6-dev-i386
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on an RPM-based distro, you can do this:

```
# yum provides '*sys/defs.h'
```

and let the tool do the hard part.

Comment: and what does it do exactly?

Comment: Scans your RPM database and tells you the name of the RPM which supplies the file ending with "sys/defs.h".